# Multithreaded in java

Tags: java

I have a multithreaded program where I want the one of the thread to print the statement after all the thread finished.How can I do that? and How do I know that all the threads finished?

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); ++i) {
            pool.execute (new ThreadProcessRunnable (args));
    }


    public class ThreadProcessRunnable implements Runnable {
           public void run() {


           System.out.println("last thread should execute this");
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you want a simpler solution, you could use something like a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other ways? Seems I cannot get it work.

Comment: I've done a REALLY basic proof of concept, check the answer

Comment: The accepted answer has a race condition that means you might get more than one "last thread" message, check my alternative for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a REALLY basic example/concept of using a `CountDownLatch`

```
public class TestCountDownLatch {

  private static CountDownLatch latch;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    latch = new CountDownLatch(10);
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      pool.execute(new Worker(i));
    }
  }

  public static class Worker implements Runnable {

    private int number;

    public Worker(int number) {
      this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

      try {
        System.out.println(number + " is sleeping...");
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)));
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      }

      System.out.println(number + " is Completed...");
      latch.countDown();

      if (latch.getCount() == 0) {

        System.out.println(number + " was last...");

      }

    }
  }
}
```

**Simple Single Thread Test Case**

```
public class TestCountDownLatch {

  private static CountDownLatch latch;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
      pool.execute(new Worker(i));
    }
  }

  public static class Worker implements Runnable {

    private int number;

    public Worker(int number) {
      this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

      try {
        System.out.println(number + " is sleeping...");
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)));
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      }

      System.out.println(number + " is Completed...");
      latch.countDown();

      if (latch.getCount() == 0) {

        System.out.println(number + " was last...");

      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems it doesn't execute this if (latch.getCount() == 0) if there is only one thread.

Comment: I'm assuming you set the size of the original latch to 1?

Comment: No. I use the array size. It works for one thread if I change if (latch.getCount() == 0)  to if (latch.getCount() == 1)

Comment: There is a race condition in this code: since you first decrement the latch and then get its value, it's possible for more than one thread to print the "was last" message (t1 decrements to 1, t2 decrements to 0, t1 gets count 0, t2 gets count 0). My answer avoids this by using AtomicInteger's atomic `decrementAndGet` operation, so only one thread will ever get a zero.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like an ideal use case for `ExecutorService.invokeAll`:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); ++i) {
    tasks.add (Executors.callable(new ThreadProcessRunnable (args)));
}
List<Future<Object>> futures = pool.invokeAll(tasks);
System.out.println("All tasks finished");


public class ThreadProcessRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

`invokeAll` blocks until all the tasks in the supplied `List` are complete.

If you absolutely must have the `println` inside one of the threads' `run` methods, then the simplest approach I can think of would be to keep some sort of counter in an `AtomicInteger`

```
public class ThreadProcessRunnable implements Runnable {
  private AtomicInteger taskCounter;

  public ThreadProcessRunnable(AtomicInteger counter) {
    this.taskCounter = counter;
  }

  public void run() {
    // do stuff
    if(taskCounter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
      System.out.println("I am the last thread and I am about to finish");
    }
  }
}

// Main class
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
AtomicInteger taskCounter = new AtomicInteger(myList.size());
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); ++i) {
    pool.execute(new ThreadProcessRunnable(taskCounter));
}
```

The key thing that makes this work is that `taskCounter.decrementAndGet` is *atomic* - if the value of `taskCounter` is initially 2, for example, and two different threads call `decrementAndGet` at the same time then it is guaranteed that one thread will see the value 1 and the other thread will see the value 0, so exactly one thread will print the "about to finish" message.  This is different from [MadProgrammer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14390306/592139), which involves a race condition:

```
latch.countDown();
if(latch.getCount() == 0) { ... }
```

where it is possible to have thread 1 decrement the value (to 1), then thread 2 decrement it again (to 0), then *both* threads see the value 0 when they call `getCount` and *both* print the message.

Comment: I have a print statement inside  public void run(), but I only want one of thread to print the statement after all the threads finished. is it possible to do this?

Comment: @John if you absolutely must have it inside the run method, then you'll have to use something like CountDownLatch as MadProgrammer has suggested

Comment: @John bear in mind that technically anything that happens within the `run` method is by definition _not_ "after all the threads finished".  I've added a possible solution that's as close as you can get, making the last task to finish print the message as the last thing it does before completing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CyclicBarrier with a barrier action ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html#CyclicBarrier%28int,%20java.lang.Runnable%29)).

> Creates a new CyclicBarrier that will trip when the given number of
>   parties (threads) are waiting upon it, and which will execute the
>   given barrier action when the barrier is tripped, performed by the
>   last thread entering the barrier.

Comment: I was asking the same question - wasn't me

Comment: @EnnoShioji: Typical SO style. As soon as as there is comment, there will be -ve comment. I think people who downvote don't even read the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can place it in the main thread. Call `pool.await()` to block the main thread until all threads in the pool have finished, then do the extra work. The code would look like this:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); ++i) {
        pool.execute (new ThreadProcessRunnable (args));
}
pool.shutdown();
pool.awaitTermination();//blocks the main thread
System.out.println("last thread should execute this");
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ExecutorService.await`, did you mean `awaitTermination` (in which case you need to `shutdown` the executor first)?

Comment: Thank you, I have to place the print statement inside the run.